# ASP.Net Intranet - Windows Authentication - Delay in allowing access

Tags: asp.net, windows-authentication, intranet

We have an ASP.Net application running in IIS 7.5 Windows Server 2008. Anonymous access is turned off. WIndows Authentication is turned on. NTLM then Negotiate in the providers. Users are logged into AD and can access the site with their network credentials. When we reboot the server there is about a 2 hour delay until the site recognizes the network credentials and allows the users back into the site. It just gives them the login prompt over and over and eventually throws the unauthorized http status error. Is this normal to have such a long wait for what seems to be propagation or should it recognize those credentials immediately?

Comment: Can you please share the Settings of your application pool ? 

go to IIS -> Application Pools -> <Select the relevent pool> -> Right CLick -> Advance Settings.

Comment: There are many, which in particular? We are using Network Service for the identity. Have tried the AppPool with  same result.